# Commutative diagram in defining local degree

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

This is from Hatcher's [*Algebraic Topology*](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf) page 136.

Suppose continuous map $f: S^n \to S^n$ $(n>0)$ has the property that for some $y \in S^n$, the preimage $f^{-1}(y)$ consists only finitely many points $x_1, \ldots, x_n$.

Let $U_1 \ldots, U_m$ be disjoint neighborhoods of these points, mapped by $f$ to a neighborhood $V$ of $y$, then $f(U_i-x_i)\subset V-y$ for each $i$.

We use the following commutative diagram to define **local degree** of $f$ at $x_i$:

[image]

$k_i, p_i$ are induced by inclusions, and $j:H_n(S^n) \to H_n(S^n,S^n-f^{-1}(y))$ is the homomorphism in long exaxt sequence for pair $(S^n,S^n-f^{-1}(y))$.

The top homomorphism $f_*$ becomes multiplication by an integer, defined to be **local degree** of $f$ at $x_i$, denoted by $\deg f \mid {x_i}$.

---

**My question:**

How can I show that this diagram really commutes?

Related question: [Local Degree of a map between $n$-spheres](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2205452)

Comment: The $inverse$ is difficult to give for the excision theorem but the diagonal maps are just inclusions. And we can check that the diagram commutes at space level and then just pass to homology to have a commutative diagram, all vertical maps are just inclusions and all horizontal maps are $f$ so to verify that the bottom square commutes we start with a point $p \in S^n$ in the bottom left corner, then we can either apply $f$ first and then an inclusion or an inclusion and then $f$, both yield the same result because if $i$ is an inclusion $i(x)=x$ per definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The commutativity of the upper half is trivial because it is obtained from a commutative diagram of pairs of topological spaces and maps of pairs by applying the functor $H_n$.

The commutativity of the right lower square follows from the fact that the long exact sequence of a pair is *natural* (see the chapter "Naturality" in Hatcher Section 2.1). Simply consider the map of pairs $f : (S^n,S^n \setminus f^{-1}(y)) \to (S^n,S^n \setminus \{y \})$.

Similarly the left lower triangle commutes. Just consider the map of pairs $id : (S^n,S^n \setminus f^{-1}(y)) \to (S^n,S^n \setminus \{x_i \})$.