# Understanding degrees of maps and the boundary map in singular homology

Tags: algebraic-topology

A couple of questions here:
1) Since $S^1$ is a CW complex with 1- one cell and 1- zero cell, $H_{k}(S^1) = 0$ for all $k > 1$. So therefore for any map $\sigma : \Delta^{2} \rightarrow S^{1}$ we have  $\partial\sigma = 0$ where $\partial$ is the second boundary map in singular homology. I cant see how that is possible. Is there a way to visualize that? Is there a way to prove that using only the definition of the boundary map?

2)
Let $f : S^n \rightarrow S^n$ be continuous. The induced map $f_{\ast}: H_n(S^{n}) \rightarrow H_n(S^{n})$  is a homomorphism from $Z$ to $Z$ so it must be the form of $f_{\ast}(1) = n$. We say $n$ is the degree of the map $f$. If we look at maps $g: S^{1} \rightarrow S^{1}$ then the degree of the map will be the amount of times the circle wraps around it self. I want to know how to formally prove that.

3) Does there exist a bijective map from $S^{n} \rightarrow S^{n}$ of degree zero?

4)How can you understand the degree of a map from $S^{n}$ to $S^{n}$ if the map isnt a rotation, projection, or reflection?

Comment: lots of questions!

For the first one, you can try the cellular approximation theorem. It's actually easier to prove using cellular homology (in which case its obvious.) I don't know how to get it right from definition with singular homology, but you can also prove it with mayer-vietoris.

for (2) It depends on what you mean. I don't know how to formalize "wraps around n-times." If you agree that $\pi_1(S^1)$ does this, then see the Hurewicz theorem. Another way to make this formal is to use

Comment: local degree as is done [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2205452/local-degree-of-a-map-between-n-spheres) by counting preimages.

for (3), no: $S^n$ is compact and Hausdorff so a continuous and bijective self-map is necessarily a homeomorphism, and hence induces an isomorphism on homology.

(4): I'm not sure it's so easy... if the map is smooth, you can look up the definition from differential topology, which is more intuitive, although similar to the local degree notion I linked to above.

Comment: @AndresMejia For the first one I knew that higher homology groups of $S^{1}$ vanish because I used cellular homology. Then I was mind blown when I tried to understand it just using singular homology.

Comment: @AndresMejia Thank you for answer to 3, I want to bang my head against the wall for not thinking about that (haha), And I am going to check your link regarding smooth maps.